# how to setup linedit support CCL in initial file?

Tags: autocomplete, lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp, ccl

I use quicklisp to install linedit, http://www.cliki.net/Linedit say "Should work on Lispworks and OpenMCL/CCL." how to write $HOME/.ccl-init.lisp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime, linedit has been made to work with ccl (linedit 0.17.5 with ccl 1.8).

I added this to .ccl-init.lisp:

```
(when (interactive-stream-p *standard-input*)
  (ql:quickload "linedit")
  (funcall (intern "INSTALL-REPL" :linedit)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Linedit through Quicklisp on CCL 1.7 on Linux and I don't think it works. Observe:

```
? (ql:quickload "linedit")
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/dist/quicklisp/2011-07-30/systems.txt">
[...]
[package linedit]...........................
("linedit")
? (linedit:install-repl)
> Error: LINEDIT:INSTALL-REPL is unsupported on Clozure Common Lisp.
> While executing: LINEDIT:INSTALL-REPL, in process listener(1).
> Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> Type :? for other options.
1 >
```

I also do not see "Should work on Lispworks and OpenMCL/CCL." mentioned on the page you linked to. It appears to be mostly SBCL specific.

`rlwrap` does work but that only gives you history, not completion.

Comment: http://www.cliki.net/Linedit this page say, I paste worry url. And https://gist.github.com/1140214 to generate completion file.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1140214 is good. And i have used it and rlwrap to run CCL,